# Is there any shorthand method to convert array of string array with header as first array to Objects of array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

Is there any shorthand method to convert array of string array with header as first array (Input as shown below) to Objects of array (as expected output shown below)

Using for loop we can achieve this, I am looking for any short hand and optimized solution to do this.

Let me know if is there any easy and optimized method to implement this.

**Input**

[image]

```js
[
  ['fromAge', 'toAge', 'gender', 'institutionalRaf'],
  [0, 10, 'F', '1.5'],
  [11, 20, 'F', '2.5']
]
```

**Expected Output :**

```
[{
   fromAge : 0,
   toAge: 10,
   gender: "F",
   institutionalRaf : "1.5"
},
{
   fromAge : 11,
   toAge: 20,
   gender: "F",
   institutionalRaf : "2.5"
}
...
]
```

Comment: please post the raw data instead of images

Comment: If you could, please edit  *your actual code* as text into your question - images of code *alone* are [tedious and difficult](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question) to work with and debug. It forces those who would otherwise love to help you to [transcribe your image](https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode) first, which is a waste of time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `map` and `reudce`

- Take the first element as `header` and rest of element as `values`
- Loop through the `values` array for each element build a object with key from `header` and value from `element`

```js
let data = [["fromAge","toAge","gender","institutionalRaf"],["1",'4','m','12'],["4",'12','f','22'],["10",'20','m','109']]
let [header,...values] = data

let final = values.map(v=> {
  return v.reduce((op,inp,index)=>{
    op[header[index]] = inp
    return op
  },{})
})

console.log(final)
```

Answer (score 3):

You could separate the keys and the values and map the value as object with the keys.

```js
var array = [['fromAge', 'toAge', 'gender', 'institutionalRaf'], [0, 10, 'F', '1.5'], [11, 20, 'F', '2.5']],
    [keys, ...values] = array,
    result = values.map(a => Object.assign(...keys.map((k, i) => ({ [k]: a[i] }))));

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 2):

I'd shift out the first array of keys, then `.map` to create entries and create the objects using `Object.fromEntries`:

```js
const arr = [
  ['a', 'b', 'c'],
  [1, 2, 3],
  [4, 5, 6]
];

const keys = arr.shift();
const output = arr.map(values =>
  Object.fromEntries(
    values.map((value, i) => [keys[i], value])
  )
);

console.log(output);
```

`Object.fromEntries` is a relatively new method. On older environments, either use a polyfill, or create the object with `reduce` instead:

```js
const arr = [
  ['a', 'b', 'c'],
  [1, 2, 3],
  [4, 5, 6]
];

const keys = arr.shift();
const output = arr.map(values => (
  values.reduce((a, value, i) => {
    a[keys[i]] = value;
    return a;
  }, {})
));

console.log(output);
```

Answer (score 1):

If keys are fixed we can use the simple approach like below

```js
let arr=[
  ['fromAge', 'toAge', 'gender', 'institutionalRaf'],
  [0, 10, 'F', '1.5'],
  [11, 20, 'F', '2.5']
];
let arr1=arr.slice();
let x=arr1.shift();
let x1=arr1.map(a=>(
                    {
                      [x[0]]:a[0],
                      [x[1]]:a[1],
                      [x[2]]:a[2],
                      [x[3]]:a[3],
                      
                    }
                   )
                 )
console.log(x1);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `destructuring`, `map` and `reduce`

```js
const array = [
  ['fromAge', 'toAge', 'gender', 'institutionalRaf'],
  [0, 10, 'F', '1.5'],
  [11, 20, 'F', '2.5']
]
const [keys, ...values] = array
const result = values.map((value) => value.reduce((a, b, index) => ({...a, [keys[index]]: b}), {}), [])
console.log("result",result)
```